# Bootstrap nav menu item full width in moblie size not working?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have navbar menu its working fine in all screens except when it turn to mobile its items do not have full width.
[enter image description here][1]

Here is the image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cvWo.png

```
    <nav id="navigationSec" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navCollapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

    <a href="#top" class="navbar-brand">waterbrain</a>
    </div >
     <div id="navCollapse" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right text-center ">
        <li><a href="#aboutSec">Me</a><li>
        <li><a href="#portfolioSec">Portfolio</a><li>
        <li><a href="#skillSec">Skills</a><li>
        <li><a href="#contactSec">Contact</a><li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: you tried to set size with div >ul >li >a >

Comment: We need the CSS too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `navbar-right` instead of `pull-right`.

Try this

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-center ">
    <li><a href="#aboutSec">Me</a><li>
    <li><a href="#portfolioSec">Portfolio</a><li>
    <li><a href="#skillSec">Skills</a><li>
    <li><a href="#contactSec">Contact</a><li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add that for responsive view

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```